# Delete all but multiple lines across multiple files

Tags: awk, vim, regular-expression, delete

I have a whole bunch of files with certain patterns

```
ABCD: 
Something 1 
Anything 2

EFGH:
Something 3
Anything 4

ABCD:
Something 5
Anything 6

HIJK:
Something 7
Anything 8
```

I want to retain the second line after ABCD and delete everything else in all these files. On a single file, this can be achieved using vim by the following commands

```
/ABCD\_[^a-zA-Z] (*searches the pattern*)
qaq              (*flush register*)
:g//norm! "A3Y   (*yank 3 lines including pattern into register A*)
ggVG"ap          (*delete everything else*)
```

Then I can perform some easy regex searches to delete the ABCDs and Somethings to be left with the correct Anythings.

However using `args` and `argdo` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126789/vim-run-a-command-on-multiple-files) for multiple files throws up errors "Not an editor command" at the second operation above. Same thing happens if I bypass the second, and go directly to the third and fourth. I am performing `args` and `argdo` after each step.

Any recommendations staying within or going beyond vim?

Answer (score 2):

Try making the whole thing into one giant `normal!` command:

```
:argdo norm! /ABCD\_[^a-zA-Z]<C-v><CR>qaq:g//norm! "A3Y<C-v><CR>ggVG"ap
```

Using `<C-v><cr>` allows you to enter a literal carriage return. This fixes your problem, but there's still a lot of things about your approach that isn't ideal.

For example:

- There's no need to search for something, and then use `:g//`. Instead, just use `:g/ABCD\_[^a-zA-Z]` instead.
- You can use `\_A` instead of `\_[^a-zA-Z]`
- There is no need to make the global command do a normal command. Instead, do an ex command and you won't need to clear register 'a'. So do `:g/ABCD\_A/3ay`.

Putting all of this together, I'd recommend

```
:argdo norm! :g/ABCD\_A/3ya<C-v><CR>ggVG"ap
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are also looking for an answer using `awk`:

```
awk '/ABCD/ {getline; getline; print}' input
```